# Enlarge the chessboard and make it bigger than "largeboard"

Tags: xskak

I'm using the `xskak`  package preparing puzzles for our club meetings. The biggest predefined size in the package is `largeboard`. I'd like to make the chessboard even bigger, as large as possible for a US letter sized sheet of paper.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\noindent\chessboard[boardfontsize=0.1\textwidth]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Vielen, vielen Dank! Da ist genau was ich gesucht habe.